# Why is MemoryCache.Remove() method not always working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0, memorycache

I have a wrapper class for Memory cache, its rather straight forward and lets me just set some defaults. However, I noticed that during my regression tests, that the .Remove method from memory cache does not work 100% of the time.

I'm wondering if anyone is aware of some bug with it or maybe my wrapper is causing the problem potentially? I don't see how though. If I run the regression test I have in place it will fail and then on next run without any code changes it succeeds. When I debug I found that it was because the cache was not refreshed. Basically the item I put in the cache still had the value from first time it was inserted.

The logic goes like this:

```
//insert record to database
//create cache
//insert second record to database
//remove cache
//create new cache
```

Has anyone encountered a problem like this?

```
internal class CacheService : ICacheService
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
    private const int DefaultCacheDuration = 3600;

    public CacheService(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public void Create(string? key, object? value, int durationInMinutes)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key) || value == null) return;

        if (durationInMinutes <= 0) durationInMinutes = DefaultCacheDuration;
        _memoryCache.Set(key, value, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(durationInMinutes));
    }

    public T? Get<T>(string? key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
        {
            return default;
        }
        return _memoryCache.TryGetValue<T>(key, out var value) ? value : default;
    }

    public void Remove(string? key)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
        {
            _memoryCache.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The cache key is a constant value so its not getting caught by null checks.

Edit:
`ICacheService` is injected under `DependencyInjectionScope.Transient scope`.

The regression test is one long test so the cache when it is setup, it is only setup once and the injection gets it from the same pool.

The entire test is on a single thread and I never call `MemoryCache.Clear()`

Comment: How do you know the cache was not refreshed?  Are you reusing the same [`MemoryCache`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs) in multiple regression tests?  Can you [edit] your question to share how you use `CacheService` in your regression tests?  Are you sharing instances of `MemoryCache` across threads by any chance?

Comment: And what about access across threads?  Are your tests being run in multiple threads?  Do you ever call [`MemoryCache.Clear()`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs#L289)?

Comment: @dbc Single Thread and never call Clear.

Comment: probably is probably with your tests

Comment: If there's no multithreading involved I don't have a guess what the problem might be other than to second @GarrGodfrey's guess.  Sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you mentioned is that, in the first execution, the memory cache is empty because the key in the memory cache only receives a value after the first execution.